# Accessing value from address in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Here is my code

```
struct ukai { int val[1]; };
struct kai { struct ukai daddr; struct ukai saddr; };

struct kai *k, uk;
uk.saddr.val[0] = 5;
k = &uk;
k->saddr.val[0] = 6;
unsigned int *p = (unsigned int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
p[0] = k;    
int *vp;
vp = ((uint8_t *)p[0] + 4);
printf("%d\n", *vp);
```

This produces a segmentation fault. However if we replace the last line with `printf("%u\n", vp)` it gives the address i.e. `&(k->saddr.val[0])`. However I am unable to print the value present at the address using `p[0]` but able to print it using `k->saddr.val[0]`.

I have to use `p` pointer in some way to access value at `val[0]`, I can't use pointer `k`. I need help here, whether it is even possible or not please let me know.

Comment: Please provide the definition of the `struct kai` and explain what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `p[0] = k;` and `vp = ((uint8_t *)p[0]+4);` makes no sense, you need to explain what you want to actually do.

Comment: @nos it looks like `vp` is going to hold the address of the second dword in `uk` of `struct kai`...

Comment: Definition of structures:  struct ukai {
    int val[1];
};
struct kai {
    struct ukai daddr;
    struct ukai saddr;
};

Comment: What is the size of `int` on your machine? what is the size of `uk` (`sizeof(uk)`)?

Comment: @AlexLop. size of int is 4 bytes and sizeof(uk) is 8 bytes.

Comment: So you start off with a pointer to `kai.saddr.val[0]`.  Do some obfuscated stuff to get a pointer to `kai.saddr.val[1]`, and then dereference it.  As `kai.saddr.val` is an array with one element, you have just derefenced something beyond the bounds of the array, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: So the only thing I can think of is that the pointer on your machine is 64 bits. what is the `sizeof(k)`?

Comment: Also, if you want to store a pointer as an unsigned integral type, you should use `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons no dereferencing of *something* beyond the array bounds is done here...

Comment: @AlexLop. sizeof(k) is 8 bytes i.e. 64 bits as you said. Just wondering how that is a problem? because vp == &(k->saddr.val[0])

Comment: @avinashkrc if `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes, and `sizeof(pointer)` is 8 bytes, how do you expect an int to hold a pointer?

Comment: It depends on the linkage, once the address may be in bounds of 32 bits, another time it would be at the upper 32 bits range. In this case `unsigned int` is unable to hold the whole address. Try using `uintptr_t *` instead of  `unsigned int *` for `p`.

Comment: @AlexLop. thanks for the input yeah it worked. Sorry for missing this size issue.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'll add the answer in the answer section. You can mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of "dirty" mess with the addresses done here.
Some of this stuff is not recommended or even forbidden from the standard C point of view.

However such pointer/addresses tweaks are commonly used in low level programming (embedded, firmware, etc.) when some compiler implementation details are known to the user. Of course such code is not portable.

Anyway the issue here (after getting more details in the comments section) is that the machine on which this code runs is 64 bits. Thus the pointers are 64 bits width while `int` or `unsigned int` is 32 bits width.

So when storing address of `k` in `p[0]`

```
 p[0] = k;
```

while `p[0]` is of type `unsigned int` and `k` is of type pointer to `struct kai`, the upper 32 bits of the `k` value are cut off.

To resolve this issue, the best way is to use `uintptr_t` as this type will alway have the proper width to hold the full address value.

```
uintptr_t *p = malloc(sizeof(uintptr_t));
```

**Note**: `uintptr_t` is optional, yet common.  It is sufficient for a `void*`, but maybe not a function pointer. For compatible code, proper usage of `uintptr_t` includes *object pointer* --> `void *` --> `uintptr_t` --> `void *` --> *object pointer*.

Comment: Notes: `uintptr_t` is optional, yet common.  It is sufficient for a `void*`, but maybe not a function pointer.    Proper uses of not shown which   includes _object pointer_ --> `void *` --> `uintptr_t` --> `void *` --> _object pointer_.

Comment: @chux Probably you are right if we want to be 100% compliant to `uintptr_t` definition. It is defined to be as large as `void*`. On the other side the standard defines that any pointer can be converted to `void*` so I am not sure the chaining *obj ptr* --> `void*` --> `uintptr_t` is really required.

Comment: Detail: Standard does not define "any pointer can be converted to `void*`".  _Object_ pointers may be, not necessarily _function_ pointers, without loss of important info.  With `uintptr_t`, the conversion steps are needed for highly portable code.  Certainly various compilers will behave well with short-cuts.

Comment: @chux I will add it my answer for future reviewers as it might be valuable for input for compatible code. But in this specific case, making few lines of portable code out of the whole  non portable project makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

The code makes no sense:

- `p[0] = k;` converts the value of a pointer `k` to an `int` as `p` is a pointer to `int`. This is implementation defined and loses information if pointers are larger than type `int`.
- `vp = ((uint8_t *)p[0] + 4);` converts the `int` pointed to by `p` to a pointer to unsigned char and makes `vp` point to the location 4 bytes beyond this pointer. If pointers are larger than `int`, this has undefined behavior. Just printing the the value of this bogus pointer might be OK, but dereferencing it has undefined behavior.
- `printf("%u\n", vp)` uses an incorrect format for pointer `vp`, again this is undefined behavior, although it is unlikely to crash.

The problem is most likely related to the size of pointers and integers: if you compile this code as 64 bits, pointers are larger than ints, so converting one to the other loses information.

Here is a corrected version:

```
struct ukai { int val[1]; };
struct kai { struct ukai daddr; struct ukai saddr; };

struct kai *k, uk;
uk.saddr.val[0] = 5;
k = &uk;
k->saddr.val[0] = 6;
int **p = malloc(sizeof *p);
p[0] = k;    
int *vp = (int *)((uint8_t *)p[0] + sizeof(int));
printf("%d\n", *vp);  // should print 6
```